# Standard overloaded std::abs doesn't match std::function<double (double)>

Tags: c++, macos, g++, std

I'm getting the following error

```
min.cpp:17:30: error: no viable conversion from '<overloaded function type>' to 'Container::UnaryFun' (aka 'function<double (double)>')
    this->addFunction("abs", abs);
```

when trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class Test
{
public:
  using UnaryFun  = std::function<double (double)>;

  Test()
  {
    this->addFunction("abs", abs);
  }
  auto addFunction(const std::string& name, UnaryFun fun) -> void
  {
    // ...
  }
};

auto main() -> int {
  Test eval;
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried to check the declaration of `std::abs` for argument `double` and return type `double` and looks like this:

```
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY double abs(double __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {
  return __builtin_fabs(__lcpp_x);
}
```

in `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/15.0.7_1/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h`.

It is accesible specifically for the `double` type. I've checked this by adding:

```
double a = 5;
double b = std::abs(a);
```

and this compiles without problems or conversion warnings.

I've tried to declare my own `abs` function like so:

```
inline double xabs(double val)
{
    return val < 0 ? -val : val;
}
```

and then change the following code like so to use this new `xabs` instead of `std::abs`

```
this->addFunction("abs", xabs);
```

and after this change, the code compiles.

Any ideas why the code with `std::abs` doesn't compile?

My environment:
OS: `Mac OS 12.6`
Compiler:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Command to compile: `g++ -std=c++2a -o min min.cpp`

**Update based on comments**

I dug a bit deeper, and it seems that there is a problem with how `std::function` is declared, which led to the problem above.

If I declare `addFunction` like so, without `std::function`, the problem disappears.

```
  auto addFunction(const std::string& name, double (*fun)(double)) -> void
  {
  }
```

This means that the compiler cannot figure out the matching `abs` if `std::function` is used but it can identify the matching overload if the type of the function is described directly without `std::function`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function)

Comment: Thanks @JaMiT. No, it doesn't answer why the code above doesn't compile. See my update in the question itself.

Comment: OK, you added an implicit cast to a function pointer (the type of the parameter). So you use an implicit conversion to specify which overload to use according to the function signature implied by the function pointer type. Hmm... Top answer from the proposed duplicate starts *"You can use `static_cast<>()` to specify which [overload] to use according to the function signature implied by the function pointer type"*. Are you being thrown because the answer did not cover all possible ways to specify a conversion?

Comment: @JaMiT, my question's goal is to identify why the code above doesn't compile. I haven't asked how to modify my code to make it work. The answer to my question is in my update, i.e. `std::function` doesn't allow to use overloaded functions as arguments.

Comment: Oh right. You did ask for "why", not "how". My bad. *(I do wonder, though, why it took so much effort to get such a simple explanation from you. I covered the reason with 7 words, while you took an edit plus two comments.)* I should have been looking for [Why does the following `std::transform` example need a function pointer instead of a function object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56635291), [Overloaded pointer to function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40217041), and [Why does std::sort fail to find the appropriate (static member) function overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52475395)

Comment: *"The answer to my question is in my update,"* -- Questions are for questions. Answers should be posted as answers, not be edited into a question.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that, since it has multiple overloads, `std::abs` doesn't have a single type.  That means that the compiler can't select a `std::function` constructor to use to convert it since it can't deduce a type for the constructor's template parameter.

There are a couple of ways to get around that:

1. Use a cast:

```
addFunction("abs", std::static_cast<double(*)(double)>(std::abs));
```

2. Wrap it in a lambda:

```
addFunction("abs", [](double d) { return std::abs(d); });
```

3. As you've done, wrap it in a non-overloaded function

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Miles. These are nice workarounds to directly let the compiler know the type of the `std::abs` function we want to use. Of course, these approaches will work, but the question was why `g++` doesn't compile a combination of overloaded function and `std::function`. It seems that the answer is that the declaration of `std::function` itself doesn't allow us to use as an argument a function that has multiple overloads. Replacing `std::function` with an explicit declaration solves the problem.

Comment: Like I said, `std::function`'s constructor is a template that can take any function-like type, but an overload set doesn't have a type.  No type, no template type deduction, no viable constructor call.  If `std::function<double(double)>` had an explicit `double(*)(double)` constructor it would work, but that's not how the class is designed.

Comment: `std::abs` is not addressable. The first snippet is wrong, although I'm not sure how bad it gets.